# Is the number of factors of a number always even? I believe it is

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose we are are given an integer $i$ such that $i \geq 2$. It is my claim that the number of factors of $i$ is always even. This is my justification. The factors come in pairs. That is, if $x$ is a factor of $i$, then $\frac{i}{x}$ is also a factor of $i$. Am I right?

Comment: What about a square number?

Answer (score 4):

How many factors does $4$ have?

Use your argument to prove a correct statement:

> The number of factors of $n$  is even if and only if $n$ is not a
> $\ldots$

Comment: should it be?: The number of factors of $n$ is even if and only if $n$ is not a perfect square

Comment: Bob-- that's it,

Answer (score 0):

Let me stray from traditional solution style to pose a very cool problem that has the same answer as the above question.  Once you solve it, you'll never forget this mathematics (I claim).

---

You have an infinite sequence of those traditional light bulbs, initially all off, but each with a draw string such that with each successive pull of the string the light changes:  ON-OFF-ON-OFF...

You start at the beginning and pull EACH and every string once... bulb 1, bulb 2, bulb 3, ...  Now of course all the lights are ON.

Re-start at the left and now pull the strings of every OTHER bulb, that is, only the even-numbered ones:  pull bulb 2, bulb 4, bulb 6, ...  Now of course only the odd-numbered bulbs are ON.

Re-start at the left and now pull the strings of every THIRD bulb, that is bulb 3, bulb 6, bulb 9, ...  This gives you an interesting pattern of bulbs ON and OFF.

Re-start at the left and now pull the strings of every FOURTH bulb, that is bulb 4, bulb 8, bulb 12, ...  This gives you an interesting pattern of bulbs ON and OFF.

Repeat this procedure with every FIFTH bulb, then every SIXTH bulb, then...

When you're done, which bulbs are ON?

***Question***:  How is the answer to this question "the same" as to the posted question?

Comment: So the switch for the $n$th position is thrown once for each divisor of $n$, right? And only switches thrown an even number of times leave the light on.

Comment: Almost... an odd number.  So:  which lights are ON?  And what does that have to do with the original question?

Comment: Yeah, I knew odd, but my fingers typed even. I didn't state the "only perfect squares" conclusion so that others could have that light go on for themselves.